# Где найти список всех стилевых свойств для стандартных тем андроида?

Tags: android, android-style

Собственно вот и весь вопрос. Хочу нормально со стилями разобраться, но нигде не могу найти списочек атрибутов с описанием :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) [Официальная документация по R.style](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.style.html)

2) [Сорцы styles.xml](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/styles.xml)

3) [Сорцы themes.xml](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/themes.xml)